# Spidermon: How to include message in telegram bot?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd, spidermon

I am trying to implement spidermon to monitor scrapyd:

https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/blob/master/spidermon/contrib/scrapy/monitors.py
https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/monitors.html#is-there-a-basic-scrapy-suite-ready-to-use

Currently it monitors minimum number of items and max amount of errors. In case of error it sends out a message via telegram. Somehow either the documentation must be wrong or my implementation as the amount of errors or items will not be included in the message:

```py
    from spidermon import Monitor, MonitorSuite, monitors
    from spidermon.contrib.actions.telegram.notifiers import SendTelegramMessageSpiderFinished
    from spidermon.contrib.monitors.mixins import StatsMonitorMixin


    @monitors.name('Item count')
    class ItemCountMonitor(Monitor):

        @monitors.name('Minimum number of items')
        def test_minimum_number_of_items(self):
            item_extracted = getattr(
                self.data.stats, 'item_scraped_count', 0)
            minimum_threshold = 500

            msg = 'Extracted less than {} items'.format(
                minimum_threshold)
            self.assertTrue(
                item_extracted >= minimum_threshold, msg=msg
            )

    @monitors.name("Error Count Monitor")
    class ErrorCountMonitor(Monitor):
        """Check for errors in the spider log.
        You can configure the expected number of ERROR log messages using
        ``SPIDERMON_MAX_ERRORS``. The default is ``0``."""

        @monitors.name("Should not have any errors")
        def test_max_errors_in_log(self):
            errors_threshold = self.crawler.settings.getint(SPIDERMON_MAX_ERRORS, 0)
            no_of_errors = self.stats.get("log_count/ERROR", 0)
            msg = "Found {} errors in log, maximum expected is " "{}".format(
                no_of_errors, errors_threshold
            )
            self.assertTrue(no_of_errors <= errors_threshold, msg=msg)


    class SpiderCloseMonitorSuite(MonitorSuite):

        monitors = [
            ItemCountMonitor,
            # ItemValidationMonitor,
            ErrorCountMonitor
        ]

        monitors_failed_actions = [
            SendTelegramMessageSpiderFinished,
        ]
```

How can the msg text be included within the telegram notification?

[image]

Comment: I think `msg` only appears in the standard output, as it would be too verbose in Slack, and the documentation does not say otherwise as far as I can tell, so I don’t think there’s a documentation bug here. What you want can probably be accomplished with Spidermon templates, but I’m not familiar enough with them to help :(

Comment: @Gallaecio I think there might be a thing or two missing in the documentation. The settings `SPIDERMON_SLACK_NOTIFIER_INCLUDE_OK_ATTACHMENTS` and `SPIDERMON_SLACK_NOTIFIER_INCLUDE_ERROR_ATTACHMENTS` in the [source code](https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/blob/master/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/notifiers.py) seem to fulfill a similar purpose like the ones regarding Telegram that I've mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you can set in `settings.py` or your crawler's settings.
To include only the error messages you are asking for, you can set `SPIDERMON_TELEGRAM_NOTIFIER_INCLUDE_ERROR_MESSAGES` to `True`.
If you'd also want more verbose messages in case there are no errors, you can add `SPIDERMON_TELEGRAM_NOTIFIER_INCLUDE_OK_MESSAGES` and set it to `True` as well.

I could not find any documentation for this, so I have to point you to the source code: [`SendTelegramMessageSpiderFinished`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/blob/master/spidermon/contrib/actions/telegram/notifiers.py)

Adding the following to your `settings.py` should convince the [message template](https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/blob/master/spidermon/contrib/actions/telegram/templates/telegram/spider/notifier/finish/message.jinja) to give you the full output:

```py
SPIDERMON_TELEGRAM_NOTIFIER_INCLUDE_OK_MESSAGES = True
SPIDERMON_TELEGRAM_NOTIFIER_INCLUDE_ERROR_MESSAGES = True
```

Comment: This did unfortunatelly have no effect.